# Como eu consigo a localização de todas itens na lista específicos?

Tags: python, lista

Eu quero saber se tem uma função de localizar a posição de 2 ou mais itens iguais em uma lista no python.

```
lista = []

for i in range (1, 5):
    ab = input("A ou B? ").upper()
    lista.append(ab)
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais "pythonica" é usando o list comprehension:

exemplo:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 7]

indices = [i for i, n in enumerate(lista) if n == 2]  # Neste exemplo 2 é o número a ser buscado

print(indices)
[1, 4, 6]
```